# Can't restore tensorflow variables

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a class as follows and the `load` function returns me the tensorflow saved graph.

```
class StoredGraph():
     .
     .
     .

     def build_meta_saver(self, meta_file=None):
         meta_file = self._get_latest_checkpoint() + '.meta' if not meta_file else meta_file
         meta_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_file)
         return meta_saver

    def load(self, sess, saverObj):
        saverObj.restore(sess, self._get_latest_checkpoint())
        graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        return graph
```

I have another class lets call it `TrainNet()`.

```
class TrainNet():
    .
    .
    .
  def train(dataset):

    self.train_graph = tf.Graph()
    meta_saver, saver = None, None
    GraphIO = StoredGraph(experiment_dir)
    latest_checkpoint = GraphIO._get_latest_checkpoint()

    with self.train_graph.as_default():
        tf.set_random_seed(42)

        if not latest_checkpoint:
            #build graph here
             self.build_graph()
        else:
            meta_saver = GraphIO.build_meta_saver()  # this loads the meta file


        with tf.Session(graph=self.train_graph) as sess:
            if not meta_saver:
                sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


            if latest_checkpoint:
                self.scaler, self.train_graph = GraphIO.load(sess, meta_saver)

            #here access placeholders using self.train_graph.get_tensor_by_name()... 
            #and feed the values
```

In my training class I use the above class simply by loading the graph using `load` function as `self.train_graph = StoredGraphclass.load(sess,metasaver)`

My doubt is are all the variables restored by loading the saved graph ? Normally everyone defines the restoration operation in the same script like `saver.restore()` which restores all the variables of the graph. But I am calling `saver.restore()`in a different class and using the returned graph to access placeholders.

I think this way not all the variables are restored. Is the above approach wrong ? This doubt arose when I checked the values of weights in two different `.meta` files written at different training steps, and the values were exactly the same meaning this variable wasnt updated or the restoration method has some fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have created all the necessary variables in your file and given them the **same** "name" (and of course the shape needs to be correct as well), `restore` will load all the appropriate values into the appropriate variables. [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#restore_variables) you can find a toy example showing you how this can be done.

Comment: thanks for the reply. can you please also tell me how can i use `sv = tf.train.saver()` and `met = tf.train.import_meta_graph()` in the same train function. My motive is to load the saved graph thru `.meta` file using `met` and continue training and also keep saving all the variables using `sv` saver.

Comment: I think [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/import_meta_graph) is exactly what you are looking for. Example 1 is doing what you are talking about. You would just need to make sure that you save again after restoring and doing more training. Also note that the initial training should be done (once) ahead of and separate from the rest of the restore/train/save process (or there won't be any files to import/restore).